# Deleting SwiftUI Items from List Based on Section

Tags: swiftui, realm

I have a TodoListView which displays a List in sections. The sections can be pending or completed as shown below. I am using Realm for my app. The problem is that how can I find out the task I want to delete, since they can belong in different sections.

What should I do in my onDelete function to delete the task in a particular section.

```
enum Sections: String, CaseIterable {
    case pending = "Pending"
    case completed = "Completed"
} 

struct TodoListView: View {
    
    @ObservedResults(Task.self) var tasks: Results<Task>
   
    var pendingTasks: [Task] {
        tasks.filter { $0.isCompleted == false }
    }
    
    var completedTasks: [Task] {
        tasks.filter { $0.isCompleted == true }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        let _ = print(Self._printChanges())
        List {
            ForEach(Sections.allCases, id: \.self) { section in
                Section {
                    
                    let filteredTasks = section == .pending ? pendingTasks: completedTasks
                    
                    if filteredTasks.isEmpty {
                        Text("No tasks")
                    }
                    
                    ForEach(filteredTasks, id: \._id) { task in
                        HStack {
                            TaskCellView(task: task)
                        }
                    }.onDelete { indexSet in
                        
                        // What to do here:
                        // can I get the element which I swiped to delete on
                       
                    }
                } header: {
                    Text(section.rawValue)
                }
            }
        }.listStyle(.plain)
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I was able to write the following code and it seems to be working fine:

```
.onDelete { indexSet in
                        
                        var filteredTasks: [Task] = []
                        
                        switch section {
                            case .pending:
                                filteredTasks = tasks.filter { $0.isCompleted == false }
                            case .completed:
                                filteredTasks = tasks.filter { $0.isCompleted == true }
                        }
                        
                        indexSet.forEach { index in
                            let task = filteredTasks[index]
                            $tasks.remove(task)
                        }
                      
                       
                    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/64428023/12299030?

Comment: Unfortunately, my Task object has no concept of sections and I don't even have a sections in the Task. The Task can either be completed or not (true/false).

Comment: I got it working. I added the code in the UPDATE.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting CoreData from SwiftUI List with Sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70399514/deleting-coredata-from-swiftui-list-with-sections)